# Multiple conditions within map nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx config:

```
if (condition1) {
    set $var val1;
}
if (condition2) {
   set $var val2;
}
```

I've read that [ifIsEvil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), also taking one request takes too much time, because regular expressions within conditions are quite complex.

I'm wondering about implementation it via `map`, but can't imagine how to write it in a good way

Comment: What for you use these conditions?

Comment: To decide wich static file to send depending on `useragent` that I check with different regexp-s

Comment: Ok. Show real conditions and usage

Comment: `set $bundle 'desktop';

    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+).+mobile|fennec|iemobile|ip(hone|od)") {
        set $bundle 'touch';
    }

    if ($http_user_agent ~* "meego|avantgo|blazer|compal|elaine|hiptop|iris|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|series(4|6)0|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
        set $bundle 'pda';
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map`

```
map $http_user_agent $bundle {
    default desktop;

    ~*android.+mobile touch;
    ~*bb\d+.+mobile   touch;
    ~*fennec          touch;
    ...
    ~*meego           pda;
    ...
}

server {
    # here you could use $bundle variable
    ...
}
```